# REST api returns 404 on some WordPress sites

Tags: php, rest-api, ip

My code:

```
<?php

public function __construct()
{
    $valid_ips = array(
        '1.2.3.4',
    );
    // It seems the problem is here! Because it returns 404 which means the endpoint is not registered.
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $valid_ips)) {
        add_action('rest_api_init', array($this, 'register_my_endpoint'));
    }
}

public function register_my_endpoint()
{
    register_rest_route('items/v1', '/get-items', array(array(
        'methods' => 'GET, POST',
        'callback' => array($this, 'some_func'),
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    )));
}
```

The problem is that it is working and registering the endpoint on some sites but not in the others. Am I doing something wrong here? I'm sure my IP that is requesting is correct as I have checked it with `https://www.ipify.org/`. Is this possible that the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` has some weird value in some wordpress sites? Or can this be modified with the client that has used it with something like `.htaccess` and the like. By the way, I have also added IPV6 in the `$valid_ips` list but no good result.

How can I fix or at least diagnose it?

Comment: The second argument in `register_rest_route` should be with out the starting slash, `/get-items` should be `get-items`. Change the multidimensional array into a regular array, instead of `array(array(` just do `array(`, just dont forget to remove the closing `)`. Also check the `REMOTE_ADDR` in each site you run this.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is working on the other sites. Just some specific sites return 404. About the multidimensional, yeah you are right. I will. About the `/get-items`, it is correct and no need to remove the slash.

Comment: That didn't work because the problem was from somewhere else. The client was behind a cloud and the requester (which is me) when requests, the IP will not be the correct one. So the if condition won't be true. Thanks anyways.

Comment: *Also check the REMOTE_ADDR in each site you run this*, thats exactly what I said =D, glad you could find the problem.